# Android Linkify both web and @mentions all in the same TextView

Tags: android, textview, linkify

Ok so I asked this yesterday:

[AutoLink @mentions in a twitter client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590384/autolink-mentions-in-a-twitter-client)

I got my @mentions linking correctly. But in order to get it to work I had to take android:autoLink="web" out my xml for the TextView. So now I get links to @mentions but it no longer links URLs. I tried doing two seperate Linkify.addLinks() calls like this:

```
mentionFilter = new TransformFilter() {
    public final String transformUrl(final Matcher match, String url) {
        return match.group(1);
    }
};

// Match @mentions and capture just the username portion of the text.
//pattern = Pattern.compile("@([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)");
pattern = Pattern.compile("(@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)");
scheme = "http://twitter.com/";

tweetTxt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tweetTxt);


Linkify.addLinks(tweetTxt, pattern, scheme, null, mentionFilter);
Linkify.addLinks(tweetTxt, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

But which ever gets called last is the one that gets applied. Can anyone tell me how I can make it link both the @mentions and still autoLink the URLs?

Edited to clarify some more of the code.

Comment: Do not use 'android:autoLink' in the TextView in your XML layout file  while you use "Linkify.addLinks". Hopes this helps to save some time for some one any way You will reach to this from answers given below

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here's my code to linkify all Twitter links (mentions, hashtags and URLs):

```
TextView tweet = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tweet);

TransformFilter filter = new TransformFilter() {
    public final String transformUrl(final Matcher match, String url) {
        return match.group();
    }
};

Pattern mentionPattern = Pattern.compile("@([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)");
String mentionScheme = "http://www.twitter.com/";
Linkify.addLinks(tweet, mentionPattern, mentionScheme, null, filter);

Pattern hashtagPattern = Pattern.compile("#([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)");
String hashtagScheme = "http://www.twitter.com/search/";
Linkify.addLinks(tweet, hashtagPattern, hashtagScheme, null, filter);

Pattern urlPattern = Patterns.WEB_URL;
Linkify.addLinks(tweet, urlPattern, null, null, filter);
```

Comment: Also, see answer from @Suraj c

Comment: Also, do not use 'android:autoLink' in the TextView in your XML layout file

Answer (score 10):

I had to Linkify.ALL before Linkify-ing the @ mentions for it to work.

Also, do not use 'android:autoLink' in the TextView in your XML layout file

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tweet);

Pattern atMentionPattern = Pattern.compile("@([A-Za-z0-9_]+)");
String atMentionScheme = "http://twitter.com/";

TransformFilter transformFilter = new TransformFilter() {
        //skip the first character to filter out '@'
        public String transformUrl(final Matcher match, String url) {
                return match.group(1);
        }
};

Linkify.addLinks(textView, Linkify.ALL);
Linkify.addLinks(textView, atMentionPattern, atMentionScheme, null, transformFilter);
```

My TextView looks like this:

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tweet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColorLink="#449def"/>
```

Answer (score 6):

Ok finally got some time to properly put in the @mention and #hashtags to a Linkify class. Instead of just overriding some of the other types of links to get it working.

This class works just like the normal Linkify, but also can do those two things.

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2007 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.use.your.own.package;


import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.text.method.MovementMethod;
import android.text.style.URLSpan;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 *  Linkify take a piece of text and a regular expression and turns all of the
 *  regex matches in the text into clickable links.  This is particularly
 *  useful for matching things like email addresses, web urls, etc. and making
 *  them actionable.
 *
 *  Alone with the pattern that is to be matched, a url scheme prefix is also
 *  required.  Any pattern match that does not begin with the supplied scheme
 *  will have the scheme prepended to the matched text when the clickable url
 *  is created.  For instance, if you are matching web urls you would supply
 *  the scheme <code>http://</code>.  If the pattern matches example.com, which
 *  does not have a url scheme prefix, the supplied scheme will be prepended to
 *  create <code>http://example.com</code> when the clickable url link is
 *  created.
 */


public class LinkifyWithTwitter {
     /**
     *  Bit field indicating that web URLs should be matched in methods that
     *  take an options mask
     */
    public static final int WEB_URLS = 0x01;

    /**
     *  Bit field indicating that email addresses should be matched in methods
     *  that take an options mask
     */
    public static final int EMAIL_ADDRESSES = 0x02;

    /**
     *  Bit field indicating that phone numbers should be matched in methods that
     *  take an options mask
     */
    public static final int PHONE_NUMBERS = 0x04;

    /**
     *  Bit field indicating that twitter @mentions should be matched in methods that
     *  take an options mask
     */
    public static final int AT_MENTIONS = 0x05;

    /**
     *  Bit field indicating that #hash-tags should be matched in methods that
     *  take an options mask
     */
    public static final int HASH_TAGS = 0x06;

    /**
     *  Bit field indicating that street addresses should be matched in methods that
     *  take an options mask
     */
    public static final int MAP_ADDRESSES = 0x08;

    /**
     *  Bit mask indicating that all available patterns should be matched in
     *  methods that take an options mask
     */
    public static final int ALL = WEB_URLS | EMAIL_ADDRESSES | PHONE_NUMBERS | AT_MENTIONS| HASH_TAGS |MAP_ADDRESSES;

    /**
     * Don't treat anything with fewer than this many digits as a
     * phone number.
     */
    private static final int PHONE_NUMBER_MINIMUM_DIGITS = 5;

    /**
     *  Filters out web URL matches that occur after an at-sign (@).  This is
     *  to prevent turning the domain name in an email address into a web link.
     */
    public static final MatchFilter sUrlMatchFilter = new MatchFilter() {
        public final boolean acceptMatch(CharSequence s, int start, int end) {
            if (start == 0) {
                return true;
            }

            if (s.charAt(start - 1) == '@') {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
    };

    /**
     *  Filters out URL matches that don't have enough digits to be a
     *  phone number.
     */
    public static final MatchFilter sPhoneNumberMatchFilter = new MatchFilter() {
        public final boolean acceptMatch(CharSequence s, int start, int end) {
            int digitCount = 0;

            for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                if (Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
                    digitCount++;
                    if (digitCount >= PHONE_NUMBER_MINIMUM_DIGITS) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    /**
     *  Transforms matched phone number text into something suitable
     *  to be used in a tel: URL.  It does this by removing everything
     *  but the digits and plus signs.  For instance:
     *  &apos;+1 (919) 555-1212&apos;
     *  becomes &apos;+19195551212&apos;
     */
    public static final TransformFilter sPhoneNumberTransformFilter = new TransformFilter() {
        public final String transformUrl(final Matcher match, String url) {
            return Regex.digitsAndPlusOnly(match);
        }
    };

    /**
     *  MatchFilter enables client code to have more control over
     *  what is allowed to match and become a link, and what is not.
     *
     *  For example:  when matching web urls you would like things like
     *  http://www.example.com to match, as well as just example.com itelf.
     *  However, you would not want to match against the domain in
     *  support@example.com.  So, when matching against a web url pattern you
     *  might also include a MatchFilter that disallows the match if it is
     *  immediately preceded by an at-sign (@).
     */
    public interface MatchFilter {
        /**
         *  Examines the character span matched by the pattern and determines
         *  if the match should be turned into an actionable link.
         *
         *  @param s        The body of text against which the pattern
         *                  was matched
         *  @param start    The index of the first character in s that was
         *                  matched by the pattern - inclusive
         *  @param end      The index of the last character in s that was
         *                  matched - exclusive
         *
         *  @return         Whether this match should be turned into a link
         */
        boolean acceptMatch(CharSequence s, int start, int end);
    }

    /**
     *  TransformFilter enables client code to have more control over
     *  how matched patterns are represented as URLs.
     *
     *  For example:  when converting a phone number such as (919)  555-1212
     *  into a tel: URL the parentheses, white space, and hyphen need to be
     *  removed to produce tel:9195551212.
     */
    public interface TransformFilter {
        /**
         *  Examines the matched text and either passes it through or uses the
         *  data in the Matcher state to produce a replacement.
         *
         *  @param match    The regex matcher state that found this URL text
         *  @param url      The text that was matched
         *
         *  @return         The transformed form of the URL
         */
        String transformUrl(final Matcher match, String url);
    }

    /**
     *  Scans the text of the provided Spannable and turns all occurrences
     *  of the link types indicated in the mask into clickable links.
     *  If the mask is nonzero, it also removes any existing URLSpans
     *  attached to the Spannable, to avoid problems if you call it
     *  repeatedly on the same text.
     */
    public static final boolean addLinks(Spannable text, int mask) {
        if (mask == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        URLSpan[] old = text.getSpans(0, text.length(), URLSpan.class);

        for (int i = old.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            text.removeSpan(old[i]);
        }

        ArrayList<LinkSpec> links = new ArrayList<LinkSpec>();

        if ((mask & WEB_URLS) != 0) {
            gatherLinks(links, text, Regex.WEB_URL_PATTERN,
                new String[] { "http://", "https://" },
                sUrlMatchFilter, null);
        }

        if ((mask & EMAIL_ADDRESSES) != 0) {
            gatherLinks(links, text, Regex.EMAIL_ADDRESS_PATTERN,
                new String[] { "mailto:" },
                null, null);
        }

        if ((mask & PHONE_NUMBERS) != 0) {
            gatherLinks(links, text, Regex.PHONE_PATTERN,
                new String[] { "tel:" },
                sPhoneNumberMatchFilter, sPhoneNumberTransformFilter);
        }

        if((mask & AT_MENTIONS) != 0){
            gatherLinks(links, text, Pattern.compile("@([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)"),
                    new String[] { "http://www.twitter.com/" },
                    null, null);
        }

        if((mask & HASH_TAGS) != 0){
            TransformFilter hashTagFilter = new TransformFilter() {
                public final String transformUrl(final Matcher match, String url) {
                    return match.group(0).replaceAll("#", "%23");
                }
            };

            gatherLinks(links, text, Pattern.compile("#([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)"),
                new String[] { "http://twitter.com/#!/search/" },
                null,hashTagFilter);
        }

        if ((mask & MAP_ADDRESSES) != 0) {
            gatherMapLinks(links, text);
        }

        pruneOverlaps(links);

        if (links.size() == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        for (LinkSpec link: links) {
            applyLink(link.url, link.start, link.end, text);
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     *  Scans the text of the provided TextView and turns all occurrences of
     *  the link types indicated in the mask into clickable links.  If matches
     *  are found the movement method for the TextView is set to
     *  LinkMovementMethod.
     */
    public static final boolean addLinks(TextView text, int mask) {
        if (mask == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        CharSequence t = text.getText();

        if (t instanceof Spannable) {
            if (addLinks((Spannable) t, mask)) {
                addLinkMovementMethod(text);
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        } else {
            SpannableString s = SpannableString.valueOf(t);

            if (addLinks(s, mask)) {
                addLinkMovementMethod(text);
                text.setText(s);

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }

    private static final void addLinkMovementMethod(TextView t) {
        MovementMethod m = t.getMovementMethod();

        if ((m == null) || !(m instanceof LinkMovementMethod)) {
            if (t.getLinksClickable()) {
                t.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     *  Applies a regex to the text of a TextView turning the matches into
     *  links.  If links are found then UrlSpans are applied to the link
     *  text match areas, and the movement method for the text is changed
     *  to LinkMovementMethod.
     *
     *  @param text         TextView whose text is to be marked-up with links
     *  @param pattern      Regex pattern to be used for finding links
     *  @param scheme       Url scheme string (eg <code>http://</code> to be
     *                      prepended to the url of links that do not have
     *                      a scheme specified in the link text
     */
    public static final void addLinks(TextView text, Pattern pattern, String scheme) {
        addLinks(text, pattern, scheme, null, null);
    }

    /**
     *  Applies a regex to the text of a TextView turning the matches into
     *  links.  If links are found then UrlSpans are applied to the link
     *  text match areas, and the movement method for the text is changed
     *  to LinkMovementMethod.
     *
     *  @param text         TextView whose text is to be marked-up with links
     *  @param p            Regex pattern to be used for finding links
     *  @param scheme       Url scheme string (eg <code>http://</code> to be
     *                      prepended to the url of links that do not have
     *                      a scheme specified in the link text
     *  @param matchFilter  The filter that is used to allow the client code
     *                      additional control over which pattern matches are
     *                      to be converted into links.
     */
    public static final void addLinks(TextView text, Pattern p, String scheme,
            MatchFilter matchFilter, TransformFilter transformFilter) {
        SpannableString s = SpannableString.valueOf(text.getText());

        if (addLinks(s, p, scheme, matchFilter, transformFilter)) {
            text.setText(s);
            addLinkMovementMethod(text);
        }
    }

    /**
     *  Applies a regex to a Spannable turning the matches into
     *  links.
     *
     *  @param text         Spannable whose text is to be marked-up with
     *                      links
     *  @param pattern      Regex pattern to be used for finding links
     *  @param scheme       Url scheme string (eg <code>http://</code> to be
     *                      prepended to the url of links that do not have
     *                      a scheme specified in the link text
     */
    public static final boolean addLinks(Spannable text, Pattern pattern, String scheme) {
        return addLinks(text, pattern, scheme, null, null);
    }

    /**
     *  Applies a regex to a Spannable turning the matches into
     *  links.
     *
     *  @param s            Spannable whose text is to be marked-up with
     *                      links
     *  @param p            Regex pattern to be used for finding links
     *  @param scheme       Url scheme string (eg <code>http://</code> to be
     *                      prepended to the url of links that do not have
     *                      a scheme specified in the link text
     *  @param matchFilter  The filter that is used to allow the client code
     *                      additional control over which pattern matches are
     *                      to be converted into links.
     */
    public static final boolean addLinks(Spannable s, Pattern p,
            String scheme, MatchFilter matchFilter,
            TransformFilter transformFilter) {
        boolean hasMatches = false;
        String prefix = (scheme == null) ? "" : scheme.toLowerCase();
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

        while (m.find()) {
            int start = m.start();
            int end = m.end();
            boolean allowed = true;

            if (matchFilter != null) {
                allowed = matchFilter.acceptMatch(s, start, end);
            }

            if (allowed) {
                String url = makeUrl(m.group(0), new String[] { prefix },
                                     m, transformFilter);

                applyLink(url, start, end, s);
                hasMatches = true;
            }
        }

        return hasMatches;
    }

    private static final void applyLink(String url, int start, int end, Spannable text) {
        URLSpan span = new URLSpan(url);

        text.setSpan(span, start, end, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }

    private static final String makeUrl(String url, String[] prefixes,
            Matcher m, TransformFilter filter) {
        if (filter != null) {
            url = filter.transformUrl(m, url);
        }

        boolean hasPrefix = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < prefixes.length; i++) {
            if (url.regionMatches(true, 0, prefixes[i], 0,
                                  prefixes[i].length())) {
                hasPrefix = true;

                // Fix capitalization if necessary
                if (!url.regionMatches(false, 0, prefixes[i], 0,
                                       prefixes[i].length())) {
                    url = prefixes[i] + url.substring(prefixes[i].length());
                }

                break;
            }
        }

        if (!hasPrefix) {
            url = prefixes[0] + url;
        }

        return url;
    }

    private static final void gatherLinks(ArrayList<LinkSpec> links,
            Spannable s, Pattern pattern, String[] schemes,
            MatchFilter matchFilter, TransformFilter transformFilter) {
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s);

        while (m.find()) {
            int start = m.start();
            int end = m.end();

            if (matchFilter == null || matchFilter.acceptMatch(s, start, end)) {
                LinkSpec spec = new LinkSpec();
                String url = makeUrl(m.group(0), schemes, m, transformFilter);

                spec.url = url;
                spec.start = start;
                spec.end = end;

                links.add(spec);
            }
        }
    }

    private static final void gatherMapLinks(ArrayList<LinkSpec> links, Spannable s) {
        String string = s.toString();
        String address;
        int base = 0;

        while ((address = WebView.findAddress(string)) != null) {
            int start = string.indexOf(address);

            if (start < 0) {
                break;
            }

            LinkSpec spec = new LinkSpec();
            int length = address.length();
            int end = start + length;

            spec.start = base + start;
            spec.end = base + end;
            string = string.substring(end);
            base += end;

            String encodedAddress = null;

            try {
                encodedAddress = URLEncoder.encode(address,"UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                continue;
            }

            spec.url = "geo:0,0?q=" + encodedAddress;
            links.add(spec);
        }
    }

    private static final void pruneOverlaps(ArrayList<LinkSpec> links) {
        Comparator<LinkSpec>  c = new Comparator<LinkSpec>() {
            public final int compare(LinkSpec a, LinkSpec b) {
                if (a.start < b.start) {
                    return -1;
                }

                if (a.start > b.start) {
                    return 1;
                }

                if (a.end < b.end) {
                    return 1;
                }

                if (a.end > b.end) {
                    return -1;
                }

                return 0;
            }

            public final boolean equals(Object o) {
                return false;
            }
        };

        Collections.sort(links, c);

        int len = links.size();
        int i = 0;

        while (i < len - 1) {
            LinkSpec a = links.get(i);
            LinkSpec b = links.get(i + 1);
            int remove = -1;

            if ((a.start <= b.start) && (a.end > b.start)) {
                if (b.end <= a.end) {
                    remove = i + 1;
                } else if ((a.end - a.start) > (b.end - b.start)) {
                    remove = i + 1;
                } else if ((a.end - a.start) < (b.end - b.start)) {
                    remove = i;
                }

                if (remove != -1) {
                    links.remove(remove);
                    len--;
                    continue;
                }

            }

            i++;
        }
    }
}

class LinkSpec {
    String url;
    int start;
    int end;
}
```

Comment: After copying this class, `Regex` is showing error. Is it a library?

Comment: @typedef Regex is the class android.text.util.Regex.java, http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/android/text/util/Regex.java/?v=source

Answer (score 2):

I figured out a way to make this work. It is a little bit hacky but it got the job done. If anyone knows of a more appropriate way to do this please do let me know.

To get it working I made myself a copy of the Linkify class and edited the part that handles the linkifying for phone numbers to do @mention links instead.

[Here is where I found my copy of the linkify class](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/cupcake/frameworks/base/core/java/android/text/util/Linkify.java)

I changed this:

```
if ((mask & PHONE_NUMBERS) != 0) {
            gatherLinks(links, text, Regex.PHONE_PATTERN,
                new String[] { "tel:" },
                sPhoneNumberMatchFilter, sPhoneNumberTransformFilter);
        }
```

into this:

```
if ((mask & PHONE_NUMBERS) != 0) {
    gatherLinks(links, text, Pattern.compile("@([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)"),
        new String[] { "http://www.twitter.com/" },
        null, null);
}
```

I called this class MyLinkify and used this code in my Activity to apply the links.

```
MyLinkify.addLinks(tweetTxt, Linkify.ALL);
```

To get the MyLinkify class to build I also had to add a copy of the Regex class into my project, [here is where I found Regex.java](http://code.google.com/p/k9mail/source/browse/k9mail/trunk/src/android/text/util/Regex.java?r=670)

Im putting this as an answer incase anyone else looking for this effect finds this thread. I realized this is probably not the best way to go about getting this to work. If anyone knows a better way to get it working please add it here and I'll select it is the actual answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

use below code:

```
 TextView textView =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);
        String str = "@aman_vivek how are u  #aman_vivek <http://www.google.com> <http://www.tekritisoftware.com>";
        textView.setText(str);
        Pattern wikiWordMatcher = Pattern.compile("(@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)");
        String wikiViewURL =    "http://www.twitter.com/";
        Linkify.addLinks(textView, wikiWordMatcher, wikiViewURL);


        Pattern wikiWordMatcher1 = Pattern.compile("\\b(https?|ftp|file)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]");
        Linkify.addLinks(textView, wikiWordMatcher1, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is tweetTxt the input String that you are linkifying or a handle to the TextView object?
If its the input string, then you are just overwriting the TextView with the output of the final call to addLinks. Given your observation, I'm guessing this is the case.

You need to pass the TextView to addLinks in both cases. Internally, Linkify will pluck the Spanned buffer from the TextView and use that, such that multiple calls to addLinks are cumulative. The WikiNotes example passes the TextView and so should you: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/wikinotes-linkify.html

Comment: tweetTxt is the TextView. Linkify.addLinks doesn't work if you try to pass in a String.