# How to put HTML (specifically a link) into a radio-button text

Tags: android, html, radio-button, hyperlink

I want to put a link in the text by the radio-button. Is there any way of doing this? The radio button inherits from TextView so there should be.

I have managed to use Html.fromHtml() to get the text into the radio button, but the link is neither underlined nor clickable.

```
final RadioButton sButton = 
    (RadioButton)findViewById( 
        R.id.radiobutton );
sButton.setText( 
    Html.fromHtml( 
            "1 månad (99:-) <a href='banan.html'>info</a>" ),
    BufferType.SPANNABLE );
sButton.setLinksClickable( true );
sButton.setMovementMethod( LinkMovementMethod.getInstance() );
```

Info should appear as a link and be clickable.

Comment: why not a radio without text and a link positioned beside it?

Comment: I don't know. Why not? My way seems more intuitive. This way I don't have to put layouts inside the radiogroup. I guess that would work, but I haven't tried it yet. If no one provides a solution with HTML I will try it.

Comment: look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997328/android-clickable-hyperlinks-in-alertdialog
similar issue (-;

Comment: in actual plain html, radios doesn't even have associated text, you have to associate a label element, who can have a link inside it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my example code above works! The problem was that I had used `android:autoLink` for the radio button, which somehow negated any code I added. So without the `autoLink`, the code above works. The `setLinksClickable` is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in the xml where you define your radio button.

android:autoLink="0x01"

That will set the TextView contained within your RadioButton to automatically linkify URLs.
For information about different values that can be passed in [see here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aautoLink)

Once you do that you wont need to use fromHtml() anymore you can simply use `setText("http://yoursite.com");`

Comment: But won't that make the whole text into a link? I need to specify both the destination URL and a text that should represent that link. I don't want just an URL as the RadioButton text.

Comment: Yes, I tried this and the link remains as text but the URL becomes a link in the display. This means that it _should_ be possible to create proper links in some way.

Comment: Find the code for the Linkify class. I imagine it would be possible to create a custom version of that class that would allow you to make the clickable text say whatever you want. This question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599786/android-linkify-both-web-and-mentions-all-in-the-same-textview has an answer with a Linkify class that I modified to work with twitter #hashtags, and @mentions.