# Twitter tags to be dynamic

Tags: android, twitter, android-listview

I wanted to display the latest tweets in a Listview with the same pattern the way twitter displays it. [check here](http://bit.ly/MAREIV) #tags @username and Urls to be dynamic within the tweet.
How can i achieve this with wherever in the tweet the # or @ or url may appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use below method to linkify the twitter and web url. Note call below method after setting the text.

```
 /**
         * set twitter and web hyper link
         */
        public static void setHiyerLink(TextView textView)
        {
            //for twitter hyper link
            Pattern wikiWordMatcher = Pattern.compile("(@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)");
            String wikiViewURL =    "http://www.twitter.com/";
            Linkify.addLinks(textView, wikiWordMatcher, wikiViewURL);


            Pattern hashtagPattern = Pattern.compile("#([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)");
            String hashtagScheme = "http://www.twitter.com/search/";
            Linkify.addLinks(textView, hashtagPattern, hashtagScheme);


            Pattern wikiWordMatcher1 = Pattern.compile("\\b(https?|ftp|file)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]");
            Linkify.addLinks(textView, wikiWordMatcher1, null);
        }
```

you need to add attributes  **`android:linksClickable="true"`** for TextView in xml

Comment: you can also see this link for more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599786/android-linkify-both-web-and-mentions-all-in-the-same-textview

Comment: Thanks for your help, Vivek...If facing some issues will surely get back to u..!!

Comment: Sure Dominic. I hope this resolve your problem. Accept answer if this resolve your problem.

Comment: plz accept the answer, so benefit for someone who have same problem.

Comment: In the twitter feeds the url fetched is for eg (http://t.co/Ieakc7ra)     I want to replace this url and just view this (goo.gl/2beOy) instead of the above url. But the url called will be this one (http://t.co/Ieakc7ra) . Please help

Answer (score 0):

This is a good example here that could guide you in the right direction. Also, googling it you will find many examples: [Loading Twitter Data into Android with Lists](http://www.sitepoint.com/loading-twitter-data-into-android-with-lists/)