# Textviews show linkable text when there isn't an actual link

Tags: android, textview, android-5.0-lollipop, autolink

In Lollipop, I have a textview which is populated by Html.fromHtml().

the text for example can be "hello.world" and it shows as a link.
In the layout for this TextView I've specified only autoLink="web" as I want links in the string to be clickable to their actual URL.

```
     android:autoLink="web"
```

This issue also persists in WhatsApp messages.

any thoughts ?

Comment: hello.world is a valid domain name in the new gTLD.

Comment: Hi. Check this thread. It implements a custom link 'generator': http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599786/android-linkify-both-web-and-mentions-all-in-the-same-textview

Comment: I have same problem, how you fixed it?