# Is it possible to make an automatic recognize for links?

Tags: java, android, hyperlink

My application is kind of a social app. My problem is that if someone uploads a text with a link in it, the app doesn't recognize the link and the link isn't clickable.

I thought to myself that maybe there is a simple way to make my app recognize a link and make it clickable.

Comment: If you're showing the links in a TextView or something, it has an attribute called autoLink which you can set to all or link `android:autoLink="all"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code for auto detecting in string.

```
String originalString = "Please go to http://www.stackoverflow.com";
String newString = originalString.replaceAll("http://.+?(com|net|org)/{0,1}", "<a href=\"$0\">$0</a>");
```

### Resource Link:

[How to detect the presence of URL in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285619/how-to-detect-the-presence-of-url-in-a-string)

### UPDATE1:

Enabling support for one of Android’s default link patterns is very easy. Simply use the `addLinks(TextView text, int mask)` function and specify a mask that describes the desired link types.

```
import android.text.util.Linkify;

// Recognize phone numbers and web URLs
Linkify.addLinks(text, Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS | Linkify.WEB_URLS);

// Recognize all of the default link text patterns 
Linkify.addLinks(text, Linkify.ALL);
```

### Resource Link:

1. [Android Text Links Using Linkify](http://www.indelible.org/ink/android-linkify/)
2. [Linkify and autoLink Need a Custom URLSpan](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/10/23/linkify-autolink-need-custom-urlspan.html)

For more details, you can go through this tutorial: [Android Linkify both web and @mentions all in the same TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599786/android-linkify-both-web-and-mentions-all-in-the-same-textview)

Comment: Hi, first thanks for your comment. 
Second, how do I use the code that is written in the link you've written?
I've added the class, but how do I use it?