# Hashtag can't use with autolink

Tags: android, hashtag, autolink

I Use HashTagHelper library [this](https://github.com/danylovolokh/HashTagHelper)
My problem is , I can't use hashtag with autolink. So i need to use autolink in textview. f.e www.google.com, http://facebook.com 
If I use HashTagHelper.Creator.create(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue), this, null); with autolink. AutoLink doesnt work.How can i solve this problem, please help me.
In additional if there is a different solution usage for hashtag with autolink, I can use it.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10145943/5250273

Comment: @UgurcanYildirim thanks for answer. I need click listiner for hashtag. I will not go twitter or other website when clicked hashtag. I have to stay my app and open new fragment when clicked hashtag

Comment: Did you find any solutions?

Comment: I used html regex